# How to match string followed by repeated pattern in regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex to match the following pattern:

`--header--` any text `-pre-` any text `-/pre-`  `-pre-` any text `-/pre-`

For example: the following text

```
--comment--
list of comments
-pre-
comment 1
-/pre-

-pre-
comment 2
-/pre-

--Answers--
list of Answers
-pre-
Answer 1
-/pre-

-pre-
Answer 2
-/pre-
```

should be returned as following when apply the regex:

```
Array
(
    [comments] => Array
        (
            [0] => comment 1
            [1] => comment 2
        )

    [answers] => Array
        (
            [0] => answer 1
            [1] => answer 2
        )

)
```

I tried the following regex `--(.*?)--.*?(-pre-(.*?)-\/pre-)+` but it only match `comment 1` and `answer 1`

Example Code:
https://regex101.com/r/59OKzs/1

Comment: You should also match whitespace - [`--(.*?)--.*?(-pre-(.*?)-\/pre-\s*)+`](https://regex101.com/r/HVCngE/2). However, if you want to get captures per each group, do not quantify the capturing group. Use [`--(.*?)--.*?-pre-(.*?)-\/pre-\s*-pre-(.*?)-\/pre-`](https://regex101.com/r/HVCngE/3).

Comment: The `.*?` before the second capturing group "swallows" the first pre block in each case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, that work if i have only 2 comments and 2 answers, what about if the number of comments is not fixed to 2

Comment: Match questions and answers separately. [`(?:\G(?!\A)|--comments--)(?:(?!--Answers--).)*?-pre-(.*?)-\/pre-`](https://regex101.com/r/AN1Zrq/1) and [`(?:\G(?!\A)|--Answers--).*?-pre-(.*?)-\/pre-`](https://regex101.com/r/AN1Zrq/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
(?:--([^-]+)--(?:(?!-pre-).)+|(?!\A)\G)\s*-pre-\s*((?:(?!-/pre-).)*)-/pre-\K
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/aEOvzZ/1)

PHP:

```
preg_match_all('~(?:--([^-]+)--(?:(?!-pre-).)+|(?!\A)\G)\s*-pre-\s*((?:(?!-/pre-).)*)-/pre-\K~s', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

To integrate appropriate keys and values:

```
// Filter empty values
$matches = array_map(function($v) {
    return array_values(array_filter($v));
}, $matches);

// Initialize two variables which we use them soon
$index = null; $finalArray = [];

// Iterate over recent matches in order to apply keys
array_map(function($array) use (&$index, &$finalArray) {
    count($array) == 2 ? ($index = $array[0]) && ($finalArray[$index][] = $array[1]) : $finalArray[$index][] = $array[0];
}, $matches);

// Print out
print_r($finalArray);
```

[PHP live demo](http://ideone.com/zkLSCf)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `preg_match_all` with `/--(.*?)--.*?-pre-\n*(.*?)\n*-\/pre-.*?-pre-\n*(.*?)\n*-\/pre-/s`

```
preg_match_all('/--(.*?)--.*?-pre-\n*(.*?)\n*-\/pre-.*?-pre-\n*(.*?)\n*-\/pre-/s',$string,$matches,   PREG_SET_ORDER);

for($i=0;$i<count($matches);$i++)
    $output[$matches[$i][1]] = array($matches[$i][2], $matches[$i][3]);

print_r($output);
```